# Have a SQL Query that needs to match a number from user input to multiple columns then to column on other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that takes a user uploaded csv and matches the number on my sql table. That is listed below. It works fine but i need another query to do something similar.

I now need a query that selects (not updates). This query will be used on my aspx page. User will enter a part number and i then display my companies matching part number along with all the other details. the flow is shown in the picture attached.

I have tried many things trying to get this to work. i have researched quite a bit and just not versed in sql enough to put this together.

This is the query that works when user uploads their csv file

```
UPDATE imports 
SET imports.AMIPartNumber = 
coalesce(AMIA.Item,AMIB.Item,AMIC.Item,AMID.Item,AMIE.Item), 
Imports.AMIDescription = 
coalesce(AMIA.Description,AMIB.Description,AMIC.Description,AMID.Description,AMIE.Description) 
FROM imports as I 
LEFT JOIN JD as JDA 
ON I.OEMPartNumber = JDA.OEMPartNumber 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMIA 
ON JDA.OEMPartNumber = AMIA.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN JD as JDB 
ON I.OEMPartNumber = JDB.OEMSubNumber 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMIB 
ON JDB.OEMSubNumber = AMIB.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN JD as JDC 
ON I.OEMPartNumber = JDC.OEMSubNumber2 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMIC 
ON JDB.OEMSubNumber2 = AMIC.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN JD as JDD 
ON I.OEMPartNumber = JDD.OEMSubNumber3 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMID 
ON JDB.OEMSubNumber2 = AMID.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN JD as JDE 
ON I.OEMPartNumber = JDE.OEMSubNumber4 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMIE 
ON JDB.OEMSubNumber2 = AMIE.OEMItem ;

select * from imports
```

This is the flow of what im trying to do (fyi AMI in picture is amipartnumbers in query above)
[image: flow]

Answer (score 1):

ok, something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM JD AS JDA
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMIA ON JDA.OEMPartNumber = AMIA.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMIB ON JDA.OEMSubNumber = AMIB.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMIC ON JDA.OEMSubNumber2 = AMIC.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMID ON JDA.OEMSubNumber3 = AMID.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as AMIE ON JDA.OEMSubNumber4 = AMID.OEMItem 
WHERE OEMPartNumber = @userInput
   OR OEMSubNumber = @userInput
   OR OEMSubNumber2 = @userInput
   OR OEMSubNumber3 = @userInput
   OR OEMSubNumber4 = @userInput
```

or maybe you only want to join on a match?  I would do that like this:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM JD 
  LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers A ON JD.OEMPartNumber = A.OEMItem 
  WHERE JD.OEMPartNumber = @userInput
UNION ALL 
  SELECT *
  FROM JD 
  LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers A ON JD.OEMSubNumber = A.OEMItem 
  WHERE JD.OEMSubNumber = @userInput
UNION ALL 
  SELECT *
  FROM JD 
  LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers A ON JD.OEMSubNumber2 = A.OEMItem 
  WHERE JD.OEMSubNumber2 = @userInput
UNION ALL 
  SELECT *
  FROM JD 
  LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers A ON JD.OEMSubNumber3 = A.OEMItem 
  WHERE JD.OEMSubNumber3 = @userInput
UNION ALL 
  SELECT *
  FROM JD 
  LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers A ON JD.OEMSubNumber4 = A.OEMItem 
  WHERE JD.OEMSubNumber4 = @userInput
```

Comment: getting this error The multi-part identifier "JDB.OEMSubNumber" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "JDB.OEMSubNumber2" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "JDB.OEMSubNumber2" could not be bound.

Comment: @Bignadad - Ok, I think I got all the typos.

Comment: your first code game me results if the OEMPartNumber matched the OEMItem, BUT if the OEMSubNumber or OEMSubNumber2 matched the OEMItem it would not work.

Comment: trying the second query now

Comment: on the second query it seems to be the opposite of the other problem. Only OEMSubNumber matches OEMItem. OEMPartNumber won't match to OEMItem

Comment: @Bignadad - hmmm... I don't understand your schema then -- I'm not doing any different between the different part types for both queries.

Comment: Would you mind testing for me? http://bakerabilene.com/interchange.aspx - here are some numbers to test. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5012364/examples.xlsx  its weird bc they are matching both ways. i have the 2nd query you posted on that page name

Comment: I think i see the problem now. the OEM numbers from JD all need to be compared to OEMItem in AMI. Right now only the numbers that are directly equal are working no matter if they are in OEMPartNumber or one of the OEMSubNumbers.

Comment: Just a note.. The query i said was working on my import task is really not working. It has inconsistencies too :(

Comment: maybe that is the key. I searched all the ones that didn't match on my import and they didnt match on your query you provided. the ones that did match on import query also matched on your query. I just need to accomplish what happens in that diagram in original post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @jd TABLE (
   [OEMPartNumber] int, 
   [OEMSubNumber] int, 
   [OEMSubNumber2] int,
   [OEMSubNumber3] int
)

INSERT INTO @jd
   SELECT [OEMPartNumber], [OEMSubNumber], [OEMSubNumber2], [OEMSubNumber3]
   FROM [JD]
   WHERE 
      [OEMPartNumber] = @enterNumber OR
      [OEMSubNumber] = @enterNumber OR
      [OEMSubNumber2] = @enterNumber OR
      [OEMSubNumber3] = @enterNumber

SELECT ami.[Item], ami.[Description] FROM [AMI] ami
   JOIN @jd ON (
      ami.[OEMItem] = [@jd].[OEMPartNumber] OR
      ami.[OEMItem] = [@jd].[OEMSubNumber] OR
      ami.[OEMItem] = [@jd].[OEMSubNumber2] OR
      ami.[OEMItem] = [@jd].[OEMSubNumber3]
   )
```

Comment: i tried this in microsoft sql server studio and it give me an error on the last select. saying "must declare the scalar variable @jd

Comment: Sorry Bignadad, mocked it up in SSMS myself and found I needed some square brackets around the @jd table reference. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working. Now no matter what the user searches OEMPartNumber, OEMSubNumber, OEMSubNumber2, etc it will match to OEMItem and bring back AMI.Item

This cross apply technique did the trick. And its quick. takes only a couple seconds to return result

```
declare @Seek as varchar(20)
set @seek = '" & enterNumber & "'

select
*
from amipartnumbers as APN 
left join (
            select *
            from JD
            cross apply (
                values 
                 (1, OEMPartNumber )
                ,(2, OEMSubNumber )
                ,(3, OEMSubNumber2)
                ,(4, OEMSubNumber3)
                ,(5, OEMSubNumber4)
              ) as xapply (lvl, OEMRef)
           ) JDT on APN.OEMItem = JDT.OEMRef
where OEMPartNumber = @Seek
or OEMSubNumber    = @seek
or OEMSubNumber2   = @seek
or OEMSubNumber3   = @seek
or OEMSubNumber4   = @seek
```